# Windows Firewall Group Policy - Outbound File Sharing Whitelisting

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, gpo

I am attempting to create and apply a Group Policy Object to a single Windows 2012 R2 server to limit outbound file sharing to our domain controllers and a single file server. I have created the policy and I can apply it to the server successfully. If I choose the "File and Printer Sharing" group in GPO and choose Block All, it works properly as I have to disable the Windows Firewall to reapply GPO from the domain, due to \domain\sysvol access being denied.

However, if I reset the rules on the server to defaults, update GPO and create a rule using the same group, but choose Allow All but under Scope, add the IPs of my domain controllers, I can still access any server on the network via file and printer sharing, it's not limited to my two domain controllers. I see the rules on the target server have been updated and I see the settings reflected under Scope. There are no duplicate Allow rules present that would override the File and Printer Sharing group.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't seem to figure out what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can get result from all policies You set I Think some another where you set another policy about firewall for get result You can get Query with `gpresult`
see that :

```
gpresult /h gpreport.html
```

or just see scope you want

```
gpresult /Scope User /v
gpresult /Scope Computer /v
```

another way you can use `rsop.msc` just see policy changed in group policy 
then Go see all group policy set and find firewall change that 
Good Luck.

Comment: I know for a fact that the firewall rules and proper policies are being applied, I can see the rules update after running a gpupdate. I'm trying to determine why the rules themselves aren't working.

Comment: I can not understand you means doesn't working for example in group policy share for all client then i set policy block share it is so clear all rules not work my means gp see all rule then decide which policy must to use for all client i hope can explain my expectations